# Probability distribution of the sum of the components of a vector following a Gaussian mixture

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let's define the random vector $(\alpha_1,\dots , \alpha_d)$ which follows a mixture of Gaussian distributions whose means are $\mu_1 ,\dots , \mu_K$, whose covariance matrices are $\Sigma_1 ,\dots , \Sigma_K$ and whose proportions in the mixture are $\tau_1 ,\dots , \tau_K$.

I am looking for the distribution of the sum of the components of this vector that is to say: $\sum_{i=1}^d \alpha_i$.

To draw a point from a Gaussian mixture distribution, an index $j$ is first chosen in $1, \dots K$ according to the proportions $\tau_1 ,\dots , \tau_K$ of the mixture. Then, the point is drawn from the Gaussian distribution whose mean and covariance matrix are $\mu_j$ and $\Sigma_j$.
Then, it comes to my mind that I can separate the problem into $K$ cases. In each case, the  $(\alpha_1,\dots , \alpha_d)$ are drawn according to only one Gaussian distribution and the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^d \alpha_i$ is thus $\mathcal N(\mu_k.I, I\Sigma_KI)$, where I is the vector with only ones.

From this I conclude that the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^d \alpha_i$ is a Gaussian mixture whose means are $\mu_1.I ,\dots , \mu_K.I$, whose covariances are $I\Sigma_1I ,\dots , I\Sigma_KI$ and whose proportions in the mixture are $\tau_1 ,\dots , \tau_K$.

However, I do not think my approach is thorough.

**Here are my two questions**:

- Is my conclusion true ?
- Is there a more formal way to find the solution ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: This reasoning is perfectly fine. I suggest using $1$ for the vector of ones instead of $I$, which is reserved for the identify matrix. Also, the variance is $1^T\Sigma_K 1$. Don't for get the transpose. If you want to make the reasoning a bit cleaner, start by defining $K$ independent random variables (draws from appropriate normal distributions). Give them names, e.g., $X_1,\ldots,X_K$. Then define your "mixture" in terms of these RVs and name it as well, e.g., $X$. Then define the sums of components $S$ and $S_1,\ldots,S_K$. Describe the distribution of each $S_i$ (you've already done that)

Comment: (cont.) and reason that $S$ is just a "mixture" of $S_i$. Really, all this is expositional. You certainly have the right idea in your answer.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question